# PHP format xml output

Tags: php, xml

This php script doesn't ouput the formatted XML that I expect from specifying

```
$dom->formatOutput = true; 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
```

**PHP Script**

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('communities.xml');

$dom->formatOutput = true; 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// get document element  

$root   = $dom->documentElement;  

$name     = $dom->createElement("NAME");  
$nameText = $dom->createTextNode("Hobbies");  
$name->appendChild($nameText); 

$community = $dom->createElement('COMMUNITY');

$community->appendChild($name);  
$root->appendChild($community); 

$dom->save('communities.xml');

$tidy_options = array(
                'input-xml'    => true,
                'output-xml'   => true,
                'indent'       => true,
                'wrap'         => false,
        );
$tidy = new tidy();
$tidy->parseFile('communities.xml', $tidy_options);
$tidy->cleanRepair();
echo $tidy;

?>
```

Is anything else needed to get a formatted output with each tag indented and on one line?

Comment: It would help if you tell us in exactly what way the formatting is not as you expect.

Comment: Tidy is going to rewrite the whole file, regardless of how much (or little) formatting DOM did for you.

Comment: @Marc-B the tidy output is shown on the page.  I am talking about the xml file communities.xml.  Tidy doesn't seem to affect that file.  My question was whether there was additional information needed to get a formatted XML file.

Comment: save problem... i think it's because when you read a formatted xml, parser inserts tabs as nodes, which is why new nodes are not formatted properly.

Comment: @see http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/471217-dom-formatoutput-issues